# How to force software master volume control in PulseAudio?

Tags: linux, gentoo, pulse-audio

I have a sound card lacking hardware volume control (Creative Sound Blaster X-Fi Surround 5.1 connected on USB). Yet PulseAudio seems to think it does have hardware volume control. When I adjust the master volume with pavucontrol nothing happens. How do I force it to do the master volume adjusting in software? (I don't want to use softvol in ALSA in addition to PulseAudio, since this would increase latency and I know PulseAudio does software mixing anyway).

I'm using PulseAudio 5.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar situation with an EMU 0202 USB audio card. Alsa shows a "PCM" mixer control that doesn't actually do anything except mute the device.

> $ amixer -c USB
>
> ```
> Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
>   Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined
>   Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
>   Limits: Playback 0 - 200
>   Mono:
>   Front Left: Playback 200 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
>   Front Right: Playback 200 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
> ```

The pulseaudio sink's HW_VOLUME_CTRL flag comes from the alsa-mixer paths configured for the default profile-set:

> /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output.conf.common
>
> ```
> [Element PCM]
> switch = mute
> volume = merge
> ```

You can tell pulseaudio to ignore it, and pulseaudio will control the volume in software instead, using something along the lines of:

> /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/emu-usb-output.conf
>
> ```
> [Element PCM]
> switch   = mute
> volume   = ignore
> ```
>
> /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/emu-usb.conf
>
> ```
> [General]
> auto-profiles = yes
>
> [Mapping emu-usb-stereo]
> device-strings = hw:%f
> channel-map = left,right
> paths-output = emu-usb-output
> ```

Then tell pulseaudio to use your customized profile for this specific card, using either an udev `ENV{PULSE_PROFILE_SET}=emu-usb.conf` rule, or loading the alsa-card manually:

> /etc/pulse/system.pa
>
> ```
> load-module module-alsa-card device_id=USB name="emu-usb" card_name="emu-usb" profile_set=emu-usb.conf profile="output:emu-usb-output" ...
> ```

This results in a pulseaudio `alsa_output.emu-usb.emu-usb-stereo` sink without the HW_VOLUME flag, and the normal pulse volume control works from alsa applications.

Comment: Thanks, it took me a while to get the names right and to make the udev rule work, but it works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for this!  Note that you can use absolute paths for the profile set and paths, so that you don't need to edit files in `/usr` -- see for example https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=110311#c11

Comment: I see this behavior with a cheap USB sound card which does functional hardware master volume for jack output but not for optical output (in the same jack socket).

Answer (score 0):

A solution who seems easier to do and maintain for USB driver was found in in the ArchWiki (again):
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio#Keyboard_volume_control

Find your sink label(int) with:

```
pactl list sinks short
```

Then you can control the volume and mute the sink corresponding to the USB drivers (let's suppose 1) with:

```
sh -c "pactl set-sink-mute 1 false ; pactl set-sink-volume 1 +5%"
```

FInally you can add those commands to your system shortcuts (or alias) to control volume from the keyboard anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how this is related to my question (hardware volume control versus software volume control).

Answer (score 0):

To change each individual channel, and after having looked everywhere, I finally found it!!

amixer -D pulse sset **Master 100%** = a**ll speakers** to 100%

amixer -D pulse sset **Master Front**  100% = **front** 100% (or whatever you specify)

amixer -D pulse sset Master **Front 100%,50%** = **front left 100% , front right 50 %**

So the same goes for **Master Center, Master Rear, Master Side, Master Woofer**

This took a very long time but finally I got it